# Find the first character in a string which isn't a specified character

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, char, indexof

I can't get my head around this. Taking a basic course and this task is about finding the index of a character in a string which isn't one of a few pre-specified characters.

The textbook says the code should be:

```
public static int sokForstaIckeBland (String s, String tecken, int start) {
for (int i=start; i<s.length(); i++)
  if (tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1)
    return i;
return -1;
}
```

String s is the text where i wanna search for a character, string tecken is the characters i wanna exclude in the search and int start is where to start the search.

I don't understand why the if statement ends with -1, what does that do?

Edit:
An example. String s = "28723709dh23ha" and String tecken = "=0123456789". When it's executed I want to find the first occurrence of the char that isn't 0123456789 and that int returned. But i don't understand how this method does that. Know it's pretty basic but you gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: It's a way to indicate you didn't find anything.

Comment: A return of `-1` means that the character you passed to `indexOf` was not found at all in the `String`.

Comment: the `return -1` is outside of the `if` and even outside of the `for` so it will only be executed if the loop went through the string without finding a suitable caracter

Comment: Why don't you ask the class instructor or TA instead of random strangers on this website? The instructor's job is to teach, so if you have questions, just go ask him/her.

Comment: I understand the -1 indicates i didn't find anything but to me it seems both return statements return the same thing. I've added some more info in the text above. 

@stackoverflowuser2010 that's a useful comment, thanks! FYI it's a book I'm learning from and no formal course wiv a teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break down the if statement:

- tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) will return an integer
- the integer will be greater than or equal to -1
- as soon as tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) returns -1 the method returns i
- i is the index of s were there is a character not in String tecken

So, this method is checking every character in s starting at s.charAt(start) (because i is initialized to start). The method compares s.charAt(i) to every single character in tecken. If s.charAt(i) is in tecken, tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) returns the index of s.charAt(i) where it appears in tecken. If s.charAt(i) is not in tecken, tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) returns -1.
That is why we are comparing to -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1)
    return i;
```

Here you are checking if the char at `i` which is `s.charAt(i)` is present in the string `tecken`, so you are finding its index in `tecken` string by `tecken.indexOf(s.charAt(i))`.

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the element is not found in the string. So if it's not found in the string then function is returning that index, because is the first
char which is not present in the string `tecken`, and that's what you want.

In this line

```
return -1;
```

If it doesn't find any char then it will simply return `-1`, indicating that none of the indexes matches the condition.

For String `s = "28723709dh23ha"` and String `tecken = "0123456789"` it will return `8`, which is the index of char `d` in string `s = "28723709dh23ha"`